# angularjs promise/timeout: Conditional timeout

Tags: javascript, angularjs, timeout, angular-promise

So is there any possibility to reach `.then()` only after `$scope.counter` reaches 5?

Here is [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ftrmgcad/)

Somehow using `Promise` ruins my watcher - it applies only when window gets resized. So i would like to know if i could do it without `Promises`

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="myController">
    <div>some{{message}}</div>
    <div>counter: {{counter}} sec</div>
    </div>
</div>

(function(){

var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('myController', function($scope, $timeout){

    //time
    $scope.counter = 0;
    $scope.message = "";

    //timer callback
    var timer = function() {
        $scope.counter++;
        if ($scope.counter > 5) {
            return;
        }
        $timeout(timer, 1000);
    }

    $timeout(timer, 2000).then(function() {
        $scope.message="body once told the world was gonna roll me";
    });       

});

})();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$timeout` doesn't return any sort of `Promise` however, if you really want to have this work off of promises, you can do the following:

```
var defer = $q.defer();
var timer = function() {
    $scope.counter++;
    if ($scope.counter > 5) {
        defer.resolve(true);
        return;
    }
    $timeout(timer, 1000);
}

$timeout(timer, 2000);
defer.promise.then(function() {
    $scope.message="body once told the world was gonna roll me";
});
```

Plunker: https://jsfiddle.net/463srkyj/

Without knowing more about your code, I'd suggest perhaps using an `$interval` instead of `$timeout` if both timeout values can be the same.  Also would ask why not just set your message inside your `if ($scope.counter > 5)` condition.